# Upgraded to Firebase 5 and having Auth issues. Cannot convert value of type '(User?, Error?)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I just upgraded my pods for Firebase and got a ton of errors. I used the Docs on the Firebase Docs webpage so I was able to fix most of them. This error I'm stuck on and need some help please.

Here are my errors: (I marked them as Error 1. & Error 2.)

1. Cannot convert value of type '(User?, Error?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'AuthDataResultCallback?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional, Optional) -> ()>')
2. Value of type 'User?' has no member 'updateEmail'

Here is my AuthService.Swift code: (All the same Swift code, just split to show errors)

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class AuthService {

    static func signIn(email: String, password: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError:  @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                onError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            onSuccess()
        })

    }

    static func signUp(username: String, email: String, password: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError:  @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
```

Error 1.

> Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password,
>   completion: { (user: User?, error: Error?) in

```
            if error != nil {
                onError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            let uid = user?.uid
            let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("profile_image").child(uid!)

            storageRef.put(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                self.setUserInfomation(profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl!, username: username, email: email, uid: uid!, onSuccess: onSuccess)
            })
        })

    }

    static func setUserInfomation(profileImageUrl: String, username: String, email: String, uid: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let usersReference = ref.child("users")
        let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid)
        newUserReference.setValue(["username": username, "username_lowercase": username.lowercased(), "email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])
        onSuccess()
    }

    static func updateUserInfor(username: String, email: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError:  @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
```

Error 2.

> Api.User.CURRENT_USER.updateEmail(email, completion: { (error) in

```
            if error != nil {
                onError(error!.localizedDescription)
            }else {
                let uid = Api.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid
                let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("profile_image").child(uid!)

                storageRef.put(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        return
                    }
                    let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                    self.updateDatabase(profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl!, username: username, email: email, onSuccess: onSuccess, onError: onError)
                })
            }
        })

    }

    static func updateDatabase(profileImageUrl: String, username: String, email: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError:  @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
        let dict = ["username": username, "username_lowercase": username.lowercased(), "email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]
        Api.User.REF_CURRENT_USER?.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                onError(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                onSuccess()
            }

        })
    }

    static func logout(onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError:  @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            onSuccess()

        } catch let logoutError {
            onError(logoutError.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) you see they changed some stuff. Essentially instead of returning a user, they now return another object ([AuthDataResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult)) containing a user.

This means you need to a [FIRAuthDataResultCallback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Type-Definitions#/c:FIRAuth.h@T@FIRAuthDataResultCallback).

Answer (score 0):

Database5 is change a lot of syntax,

In error1, you can try this:

```
static func signUp(username:String, email:String, password: String, imageData:Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user , error) in
        if error != nil {
            onError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        //Here you have to change the uid 
        let uid = user?.user.uid
        //It should be Storage.storage().reference()
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOT_REF).child("profile_image").child(uid!)
        //storageRef.put was removed and it's changed be storage.putData 
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            //downloadURL is changed too, you can read at documents of Firebase to know how to use this
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let error = error { 
                    return
                }else {
                    let profileImageUrl = url!.absoluteString
                    self.setUserInformation(profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, username: username, email: email, uid: uid!, onSuccess: onSuccess)
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

And in error2, it same error with error1, you can try this:

```
        Api.User.CURRENT_USER?.updateEmail(to: email, completion: { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            onError(error?.localizedDescription)
        }else {  
            let uid = Api.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid
            //Change here
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOT_REF).child("profile_image").child(uid!)
            //Change here
            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        return
                    }else {
                        let profileImageUrl = url!.absoluteString
                        self.updateDatabase(profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, username: username, email: email, onSuccess: onSuccess, onError: onError)
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    })


static func updateDatabase(profileImageUrl: String, username: String, email: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
    let dict = ["username": username, "username_lowercase": username.lowercased(), "email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]
    Api.User.REF_CURRENT_USER?.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            onError(error?.localizedDescription)
        }else {
            onSuccess()
        }
    })
}


static func logOut(onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        onSuccess()
    }catch let logoutError {
        onError(logoutError.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

You can read document of Firebase again to see what difference https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup